# MySQL and import stored procedure on Hibernate start-up

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, file, import

I want to update all my SPs when I run my java program (doesn't matter if it's not good practice).
Since I'm using Hibernate 4.3.2.Final, I'm trying to avoid to write my own SQL executer for MySQL.
So I'm trying to use hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files in my hibernate.cfg.xml.
It get the script, but it's not able to parse it. I've tryed with

```
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files">/Database/stored_procedures/load.sql</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files_sql_extractor">org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.MultipleLinesSqlCommandExtractor</property>
```

but I get

```
org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.ImportScriptException: Error during statement execution (file: '/Database/stored_procedures/load.sql'): DELIMITER $$ 
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$
```

the SP sql file runs fine on MySQL (tried many times) and it is something like:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS ebull.`load_friends`;

DELIMITER $$ 

CREATE PROCEDURE ebull.`load_friends`(
    IN transactionId BIGINT,
    IN chunk INT
)
BEGIN
    ...sql queries and stuff....

END

$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I think it's something wrong with the delimiters, but I don't know how to avoid them since it's a stored procedure definition.
I am starting thinking that this is not possible. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you need not use `Delimiter` based syntax in SQL script for creating stored procedures. Modify your SQL script file to remove `DELIMITER ...` parts and run the rest of your procedure code from JAVA.

**Refer to**:
[***Creating Stored Procedure in MySQL with SQL Scripts or JDBC API***](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/storedprocedures.html#create_jdbc_mysql)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it didn't work. Same syntax error.

`Error during statement execution (file: '/Database/stored_procedures/load_friends.sql'): CREATE PROCEDURE ebull.load_friends(
    Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 9`

the other weird thing is that there is no line 9 :O
the last line is line 6

Comment: I think the problem are the delimiters, it's trying to execute what is inside the SP, but it shouldn't because that is part of the store proc! it should create the sp, so follow the CREATE PROCEDURE statement instead of trying to execute what is inside.

Comment: after debugging the hibernate code with this sp:
`DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS ebull.load_friends;
CREATE PROCEDURE ebull.load_friends(IN transactionId BIGINT, IN chunk INT)
BEGIN
    CALL ebull.load_friends_user(transactionId,chunk);
    CALL ebull.load_friends_base(transactionId,chunk);
END;`

it correctly executes the drop procedure statement, but then hibernate try to execute everything upto the next semicolon, that is wrong since part of that code is part of the SP code!